# How to place dots when looping through an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I need to load an array from a json file, and place dots where they placed last time after they click save, this code wont work, any thoughts? Essentially, they can click, and dots will appear, as well as text from the drop down menu, I want it so they can click save, and it will store it in a json file, where next time the person comes on, they can click load, and it will loop through the array, placing the dots and text where they previously clicked.

```
    <style>
      #map {
      width: 100%;
      height: 1000px;
      margin-top: 50px;
    }
    </style>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <button onclick="load()">LOAD</button>
    <button onclick="save()">SAVE</button>
    <body>
      <select id="myDropdown">
        <option value="shark">Shark</option>
        <option value="kapador">Kapador</option>
      </select>
      <div id="map">

    <script>
      var fishElement
    var points = [""]
    points.length = 20
    var arrayLength = points.length;
    </script>
    <script>
      function load()
        localStorage.getItem('points', JSON.stringify(points));
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
          alert(points[i]);
          pageY + 'px'
          pageX + 'px'
          width: '10px'
          height: '10px'
          background:'#000000'
        }
    </script>
    <script>
    function handleClick(x, y) {
      var myFish = $('#myDropdown option:selected').text();
      fishElement = $('#map').append("<p style='position: absolute; top: "+y+"px; left: "+x+"px;'>"+myFish+"</p>");
      return fishElement
    }


    $(document).ready(function() {
      });

      $('#map').click(function(ev) {
        handleClick(ev.pageX, ev.pageY)
        $("body").append(
          $('<div></div>').css({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: ev.pageY + 'px',
            left: ev.pageX + 'px',
            width: '10px',
            height: '10px',
            background: '#000000'
          })
        );
        points.push([ev.pageY, ev.pageX, fishElement])
      });
      function save()
      localStorage.setItem('points', JSON.stringify(points));
    </script>
```

Comment: Don't see anywhere where you use `localStorage.getItem()` to retrieve the stored data. Also seem to be using 2 different storage keys

Comment: im an idiot, so i fixed that, but what else is wrong with it?

Comment: it says ev is not defined

Comment: syntax problems in `load()` also.  `pageY + 'px'` doesn't do anything and the `:` use isn't in any object

Comment: i fixed the load, but how would i get it to place all of the dots and words again, because it saved the coordinants in the array, now i need to to place them again

Comment: If they exist in storage on page load then parse them into  html or elements and insert them in the dom

Comment: how would i do that, should'nt it just place dots based on the coordinates of the array, then loop to the next item in the array?

Comment: Depends what *"where they were placed before"* means. If they are absolute position for example the array order wouldn't matter

Comment: essentially, the person selectes an item from a drop dow menu and clicks on the screen, a dot with the item they selected appears, after that, i want them to click the save button, where the array is store, so when the person comes on the next day, they can click load, and the dots will be placed again

Comment: So you know where that position is when you add it the first time. Make sure you store it as part of the object in the array. Then you loop over all objects in array and create and set there positions on page load from that data

Comment: yeam so it stores the coordinates each time they click, but i attempted placing the dots again, but i dont know how to do it

Comment: Almost identical to the way you do it in the click handler...except the position data is from stored object not from the event. Create a basic demo in jsfiddle.net or other sandbox site and can help better

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rbxokgf0/

Comment: also i could not get the placing of dots and text to work with js fiddle

Comment: Lots of issues in your code. Try this https://jsfiddle.net/ujw414u2/

Comment: thank you, what about the type of fish?

Comment: I scaled that out to simplify it for now to get you started. You need to add that part in where `fishname` is added to each point

Comment: ok, im not sure how to add back the fish type, i put the drop down back in, but i cant get the text to re apear